# What's the best way to make a text field with a suggested value that is shown even after it is filled?

Tags: input-fields

For example, let's imagine a simple exercise tracking app. There's a field where the user can input the target score (the score he wishes to obtain).

Then, after exercising, the user is presented a field asking what score was actually obtained. On the same field, I need a way to show the "target" value, as well as the input value.

For now, I've thought of showing the target value as a suffix, but I fear it isn't obvious.

[image: Example of field with suggested value]

I could also simply show the target value in the field's label: "Score (1000)"

Is there a more user-friendly approach?

Comment: In both the screenshot and the label example you give, you don't make it at all clear what the significance of the number "1000" is. What are you hoping to achieve by squeezing this additional information into the same field?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming it to be a "Mobile App" considering the example.
If so, rethink the UI element itself. Maybe a "slider"?

Either way, it is good to show the "Target" and "Achieved" score separately for easy demarcation, comparison purposes and also to give the user a sense of accomplishment.

Answer (score 0):

Just giving quick answers here! And you can consider leaving the interface as-is what you've designed, if it's widely applied in the application, users will figure out later.

1. You can consider having a small help icon beside `Score` to let users know that 1000 is a target
2. You can consider placing a smaller text label `Target` above `1000` to show that this is a target number
3. Color coding the actual code to reflect for example `red color` for below target and `green color` for reaching the target

Comment: those are great ideas thanks

Comment: Color coding is not accessible. Please be mindful of the portion of the population who is colorblind, or otherwise visually impaired.

Comment: Yes, colour coding is the last of the methods i gave above. But it’ll work if you consider how colour blindness works, for example, not to use green-red colour pair adjacent to each other. And instead to use shades of one colour for colour coding, and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Having taken inputs from the user, you can take a more visual approach to show the goal vs actuals. Below is a suggestion, that is based on the [Bullet Graph by Stephen Few.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_graph)

As suggested, you can also add zones as I have shown, to help the user easily see where he or she resides currently and what is an ideal place to be (and the steps that need to be taken to reach there).

1000 is the target, and 670 is the actuals. It also allows to nicely capture overshoots.
Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: I fear that this would take too much space. In a single page, there might be more than 10 fields. The fields must accept input from the user and display the target value as reference.